# Tabulating variables based on conditions

Tags: r

I have this data and I want to tabulate the columns on conditions based on `q8_12`:

```
q8_12   q8_13_1 q8_13_2 q8_13_3 q8_13_4 q8_13_5
YES NO  NO  NO  NO  NO
YES NO  NO  NO  YES NO
NO  NO  NO  NO  NO  NO
NO  NO  NO  NO  NO  NO
NO  NO  NO  NO  NO  NO
YES NO  NO  NO  NO  NO
NO  NO  NO  NO  NO  NO
YES NO  NO  NO  NO  NO
YES NO  NO  NO  NO  YES
YES NO  NO  NO  NO  YES
YES NO  NO  NO  NO  YES
YES NO  NO  NO  NO  NO
YES NO  NO  NO  YES NO
NO  NO  NO  NO  NO  NO
```

I am using the `if` function:

```
if(q8_12=='YES') table(q8_13_11)
```

and I get this error

> Warning in if (q8_12 == "YES") table(q8_13_11) :
>         the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

Anyone has an idea of how to go about this problem?

Comment: Please read about how to supply your data in [a reproducible fashion using `dput`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `by`:

```
by(dat[-1], dat[1], summary)
```

where `dat` is the name of your data frame.

```
q8_12: NO
 q8_13_1 q8_13_2 q8_13_3 q8_13_4 q8_13_5
 NO:5    NO:5    NO:5    NO :5   NO :5  
                         YES:0   YES:0  
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
q8_12: YES
 q8_13_1 q8_13_2 q8_13_3 q8_13_4 q8_13_5
 NO:9    NO:9    NO:9    NO :7   NO :6  
                         YES:2   YES:3
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to index, not use `if`:

```
table(q8_13_11[q8_12=='YES'])
```

You may also just want a crosstab:

```
table(q8_13_11, q8_12)
```

Comment: Thanks, what if i want tabulate all the columns based on q8_12=='YES'. can i loop over them?

Comment: @jonestats Look at Sven Hohenstein's answer.